# How to specify what components to retrieve for the command "force:mdapi:retrieve"?

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx

I am just getting started with sfdx and trying to retrieve all the metadata present in my sandbox using the command `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve --retrievetargetdir force-app`. It runs fine and creates a zip file called `unpacakged.zip` but no metadata in it.

How do I configure so that it retrieves all the metadata present in my sandbox(not scratch org)?

This is what my folder structure looks like:

```
.
├── config
│   └── project-scratch-def.json
├── force-app
│   ├── main
│   │   └── default
│   │       └── aura
│   ├── package.xml -> Created by retrieve command and it is plain 
│   │                   package.xml
│   └── unpackaged.zip -> Created by retrieve command but no metadata 
│                         in it.
├── README.md
└── sfdx-project.json
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to use unmanaged package , if you have package.xml in your root folder of the project try the below

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve --retrievetargetdir force-app  -k package.xml
```

Its clearly documented here on what [parameters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_mdapi.htm#cli_reference_retrieve) retrieve command can take

Comment: Thanks, I will try. I looked at the documentation but didn't know manifest file means package.xml file.