# Is there a way to identify if any reports use Fiscal Year?

Tags: custom-reports

We are changing start of fiscal year to July. 
There are no of reports in our system and i need to know which all reports would get affected with the change. Any thoughts on how we can get the reports which are using fiscal calculation. Opening and checking each individual reports would we too time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way that I can think of is use whatever tool you would like to fetch reports metadata from your organization and then using any IDE or maybe a little more sophisticated text editor (or grep or windows grep) search through file contents to find Fiscal Year column. In a result you will recieve list of report metadata files that contains that column/filters/whatever.

Comment: Which tool can be used to fetch the metadata?

Comment: Force Com IDE, Mavensmate (Outdated though) Illuminated Cloud plugin for intellij, welkinsuite, but IMO I would use sfdx cli using this answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/194793/how-to-specify-what-components-to-retrieve-for-the-command-forcemdapiretrieve using package.xml created with this https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks it worked. i have documented the steps i did to get the result as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank @user1974566 for pointing me in the right direction and credit for this answer would be his. I am just documenting what i did to get the result.

1. Download [Salesforce CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli)
2. Install the tool.
3. Build your package to retrieve using the tool here https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/
4. Copy the xml and save into your directory and name it package.xml
5. Open commandprompt (navigate to folder where you have the package.xml
6. login into your org using the command( opens up in browser and you can login)

   sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com
7. After authenticating from browser. run the command to retrieve the metadata

   sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r ./[Foldername]  -u [yourusername] -k ./package.xml
8. Above command would create a zip file in the folder you have mentioned in the command. Unzip the zip.
9. Use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and used the Search->Find in Files to search for FISCAL (you can select the folder that you want to search in. Since i needed only the reports i selected the reports folder)
10. You should get all the instances where FISCAL is used

Hope this helps to other users who have a similar need.

Here are some more reference points that i used

http://matheusgoncalves.com/salesforce-dx-useful-cli-commands/

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2016/05/force-cli-part-1-getting-started.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_mdapi.htm?search_text=login#cli_reference_retrieve